# On large diameter Atlas V fairings, why is the Centaur inside the fairing?

Tags: fairings, atlas-v, centaur

[image]

When including an image in an answer to this question: [Was New Horizons launched on a copper rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/was-new-horizons-launched-on-a-copper-rocket) I noticed that for the larger diameter fairings (Atlas 501 and up) the Centaur upper stage is submerged in the fairing.

Why?

This makes the fairing a lot longer than it would be if it was mounted only to the top of the Centaur as it is on the smaller models.

The answers to this question [Why does Atlas V have so many different types of payload fairings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13248/why-does-atlas-v-have-so-many-different-types-of-payload-fairings) don't address this issue.

Comment: Hahaha, I almost wrote the same question, then I decided I knew the answer.

Answer (score 16):

[A document from NASA Safety & Mission Assurance](https://sma.nasa.gov/LaunchVehicle/assets/space-launch-report.pdf) suggests the reason is structural:

> Thin-­skinned Centaur cannot easily support the giant 5.4 meter diameter payload fairing, so the Contraves composite fairing also encloses Centaur.

My first guess, however, was aerodynamics, particularly the [Whitcomb area rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_rule): for transonic flight, abrupt changes of cross-sectional area produce lots of drag.

The Centaur upper stage is about 3m in diameter, and the Atlas V first stage is 4.1 in diameter.

The 4xx configurations use a 4.2 meter payload fairing, so the profile is 4.2m-3.05m-3.8m; the upper stage cross section is 53% of the fairing cross section, which is a pretty significant drop.

If the 5xx configurations left the Centaur un-faired, the profile would be 5.4m-3.05m-4.1m; the upper stage cross section would be only 32% of the fairing cross section. Instead, it's faired; there's only one cross-section transition instead of two (on the 501, at least), and the first stage is 58% of the fairing cross section.

There might also be airflow/turbulence issues necking down further behind the 5m fairing that would cause structural problems; ISTR something like that related to Orion on Delta IV, but I could be making that up.

This [thread on nasaspaceflight.com](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=39661.0) discusses both structural and aerodynamic possibilities, as well as thermal considerations on the Centaur (though it doesn't explain why the 4m version wouldn't have the same thermal requirements).

Comment: Would you like to pick one?

Comment: No, I would not like to pick one.

Comment: The comment about it being done for Titan 3E and 4 sort of undermines the area rule argument, doesn't it?

Comment: Somewhat, yeah.

Comment: The structural reason could well _also_ be aerodynamic.  A wider fairing is draggier than a narrower fairing, and a fairing that necks down abruptly (like a Centaur-mounted 5-meter Atlas V fairing would be) is draggier than one that doesn't.  The increased aerodynamic drag on the fairing translates directly to increased structural loads for whatever's supporting the fairing; if the 5-meter fairing were mounted atop the Centaur, this entire (rather large) load would have to be borne by the Centaur's thin balloon-tank skin, potentially causing it to buckle or collapse during first-stage flight.