# Have there been any rockets whose payload fairings consisted of more than two parts?

Tags: rockets, payload, fairings

Most cargo rockets, such as Falcon 9, Delta IV, and many others, incorporate payload fairings to protect payloads from aero forces and heating during ascent. All of these rockets' fairings split in two upon separation. Have there been any fairings which split into more than two pieces?

From Wikipedia, the Delta IV has a trisector fairing but I don't have any evidence about how it works.

> The aluminum trisector (three-part) fairing was built by Boeing and derived from a Titan IV fairing. The trisector fairing was first used on the DSP-23 flight. The Delta IV with the extended fairing is over 62 m (203 ft) tall.

Comment: Not a cargo fairing as such, but the Apollo missions had the [four-part Spacecraft-Lunar Module Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ApolloSpacecraftLMAdapterDiagram.png) which, among other things, served as a shroud for the LM during launch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My kneejerk reaction on this was incorrect, the "trisector fairing" does split into three parts.

> After climbing into the rarefied upper layers of the atmosphere, the Delta 4 will release its nose cone to shed weight and reveal the NROL-44 payload. The trisector fairing, designed especially to accommodate large NRO and military satellites, **will jettison from the launcher in three pieces** rather than in two halves like payload shrouds used on most other other rockets.

A ULA video is embedded, this still from the animation shows the fairing in 3 parts.

[image]

Source https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/08/26/delta-4-heavy-likely-heading-for-geosynchronous-orbit-with-top-secret-payload/

A trisector fairing was also used on Titan IVs for large defense payloads and at least one NASA payload, Cassini.  This schematic shows the 86 foot fairing used for Cassini in a test configuration.

[image]

Source: [ACOUSTIC
TESTING OF THE
CASSINI SPACECRAFT
AND
TITAN
IV PAYLOAD
FAIRING](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42773353.pdf)

Comment: Are there any other LVs which use 3 or more fairing pieces?

Comment: I read that the Titan IV did but I have not yet confirmed it @fasterthanlight

Comment: @fasterthanlight I found a reference for the Titan IV trisector fairings.

Comment: Funny they have the whole upper stage in the fairing

Comment: @Antzi I asked why that was a while back, never got a definitive answer https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33255/6944

Comment: @fasterthanlight do KSP fairing count? Because those things pretty much get obliterated upon deployment into a million tiny pieces.